# Any cheats that get me past the pumps?

Tags: cheats, vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

I've reached the room where I'm supposed to go through the pipes to reservoir 2, but I can never reach it in time- any codes or mods that either move me in the reservoir of help me swim faster?

Comment: I've never played the game, but assuming you can't find any cheats with a quick google search they likely don't exist. My suggestion instead is to simply keep practising, or find YouTube videos for it. If it's a common problem, there should be an abundance of resources, but even if no one else has this problem there'll be walkthroughs etc they should give you an idea of what to do. It's possible you're meant to do something that you're missing.

Comment: A quick search reveals it's a fairly common problem with advice on other forums, but I can't be certain if it's the exact situation you encounter. If you find a solution, feel free to come back and leave an answer though!

Comment: What clan are you playing as? I have a vague recollection that *Celerity* made it easier for me on my Brujah and Toreador playthroughs. It's been a long time since I last played though, maybe time for a new playthrough!

Comment: I suspect you'll have an easier time searching for save games that put you on the other side, rather than cheats that solve one specific problem. Of course, that would also mean losing any progress you made on your own character.  (Although if there's a cheat that would give you *Celerity*, it sounds like that might help.)

Comment: @JonK- I'm playing a Nos.

Answer (score 1):

As you're specifically asking for *cheats*, here we go:

**Enable the in-game Console**

To do this on the Steam version of the game right-click on VTMB in your library and select *Properties*. Open the *General* tab and then click `SET LAUNCH OPTIONS...`. Enter `-console` in the dialog and hit OK.

---

For the non-Steam version:

On Windows right-click the shortcut used to launch the game (create one if you haven't got one), click *Properties* and open the *Shortcut* tab. In the *Target* field you need to add `-console` (**note the space, it must be included!**) to the end of the existing string and hit OK.

For a Mac you need to open `...Preferences/Vampire Bloodlines Preferences/config`, then add the following to the end of the file:

```
[appdefaults\\vampire.exe\\transgaming]
"cmdlineadd" = "-console 1"
```

---

**Launch the game and load your save**

To access the console you can use the tilde (<kbd>~</kbd>) key or the grave (<kbd>`</kbd>) key (whichever is to the left of <kbd>1</kbd>).

Once open, enter the command `noclip` to disable collision detection and allow you move through the walls to get to where you're trying to go. Enter `noclip` again to turn collision back on.

It is worth noting that **using cheats can break some scripted events in the game and should be used with caution**. Create a backup of your save before you try this.